# The smallest $k$ such that $n^k-n$ is divisible by $30$

Tags: number-theory

Find the smallest integer $k≥2$ such that $n^k-n$ is divisible by $30$ for all natural numbers $n$
I think $n^k-n$ should be divisibile by $3$ and $2$ and $5$
In fact it is always divisibile by $2$
I still can't see how to choose the smallest $k$ for which this expression is divisible by $30$

Comment: How about just computing the possibilities based on $n \pmod {30}$?

Comment: For $n=0,1,2,\ldots,14$ (mod $15$), the minimal values for $k$ are $2,2,5,5,3,3,2,5,5,3,2,3,5,5,3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$n^k=n \mod 30$$ is equivalent to $$n^k=n \mod 2 \\ n^k=n \mod 3 \\ n^k=n \mod 5 \, .$$ The last equation requires $k=5+4\mathbb{Z}$. The smallest such positive number $\geq 2$ is $5$. Now $$n^5=n^3n^2=n \mod 3 \\ n^5=n^2n^2n=n^3=n^2n=n^2 = n \mod 2$$by FLT if gcd(n,3)=1; if not then $0=0 \bmod 3$ is obviously true.

Comment: Actually, the answer is $5$.

Comment: Sry made a mistake.